# How to disable autocorrect in HTML input on Android?

Tags: android, html

I can not disable autocorrect of text input in web browser on Android.

I tried this:

```
<input type='text' autocomplete='off' spellcheck='false' autocorrect='off'>
```

Demo:
http://jsbin.com/coqum/3

Both Chrome 35 and Firefox 29 do autocorrect on Android 4.4. Is it an Android bug?

Is there a way to ask Android not to autocorrect?

### Update (March 2015)

It looks like the bug has been fixed in Chrome on Android, it now obeys `autocomplete='off'`. Firefox on Android still autocorrects.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/jivupadolu/1

Comment: What made you think that `autocorrect` would have any impact? There is no such attribute in any HTML specification or draft.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela you are quite right. autocorrect is an Apple extension, as far as I know, and probably not used in Chrome.

Comment: Use a password field? I know that won't help...

Comment: @Chloe thanks, password field will work indeed because browsers do not autocorrect it. But in my case I do need a plain text input field unfortunately.

Comment: What Chrome version was it fixed in?

Comment: Is there any known fix to this in text type inputs? Struggling with this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In experiencing the same issue I did some digging and discovered it is indeed a bug in Chrome for Android. It appears to just recently have been fixed and hopefully should be released in an update soon.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303883&q=autocorrect&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Also feel free to Star the issue to help boost the ranking...

Answer (score 6):

Currently autosuggest="off" does not work. I reported a ticket for it, so you can vote.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Open https://output.jsbin.com/qacoforama/3?output in mobile Chrome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Chrome Android autocorrect</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>

  <h3>Android keyboard shows suggestions on typing</h3>
  <p>when autocorrect="off"</p>
  <p><input type="text" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off"></p>
  <p>Tested in Chrome 70.0.3538.80</p>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Try to type something in the input field
   [image]
   [image]
3. You will see keyboard suggestions

What is the expected behavior?
You should not see any suggestions, because "autocorrect" attribute on input field set at "off"

What went wrong?
One picture with suggestions is Chrome, and another one without suggestions is Safari

Did this work before? Yes It initially started to work in Chrome 38, can't say about other versions and when it became broken

Does this work in other browsers? No
 1) Mobile Safari
There is no such problem in mobile Safari. The keyboard does not provide any suggestions when autocorrect="off"
2) Mobile Firefox
The same problem as in Chrome: autocorrect="off" does not work, so one can see some suggested words

Chrome version: 70.0.3538.80  Channel: stable
OS Version: 7.0
Flash Version:

There is an old issue where the same problem was described https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303883.

As a result the issue was resolved and autocorrect="off" was honored.
But at some moment it was broken and still does not work.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=901839

Comment: // , Would you please add some of the content of the bug report

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: http://jsfiddle.net/c9HQT/

Basically you are using Javascript to set the value after every keystroke, hopefully interrupting the auto-complete.

```
$('input').on 'keypress', ->
  console.log $(this).val()
  $(this).val $(this).val()
```

Comment: Tried the demo on my Android 4.4 phone - still does autocorrect. Thanks for idea though.