# HTML autocorrect for text input is not working

Tags: javascript, html, text

I am trying to perform some autocorrect for English words in text input. Here is my code:

```
<input autocomplete="on" autocorrect="on" autocapitalize="on" type="text" name="textinput" placeholder="Enter a test" spellcheck="on">
```

My [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2va9tgw/8/)

However, it does not seems to work on Chrome by using a desktop computer. Is this feature only applicable for mobile?

Answer (score 7):

Try using `spellcheck="true"` html attribute instead of `autocorrect="on"`

```
<input autocomplete="on" spellcheck="true" autocapitalize="on" type="text" name="textinput" placeholder="Enter a test" spellcheck="on">
```

Answer (score 4):

`autocorrect="on"` is currently a non-standard attribute.

> This is a non-standard attribute supported by Safari that is used to
>   control whether autocorrection should be enabled when the user is
>   entering/editing the text value of the `<input>`

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-autocorrect

Comment: I'm not quite sure. It looks like it may be supported on a few browsers. For example, it appears to be supported by Chrome on Android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853473/how-to-disable-autocorrect-in-html-input-on-android

Comment: Ah I see so it is only applicable for mobile site. I realized that it does not work with browser on computer as it does not autocorrect at all

Comment: Right, that's what I've seen too. Since it's non-standard, it might be hard to track down where it works and where it doesn't. I suppose it's possible it could work on Safari desktop.